# Usar switch case con un JSON - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, switch

estoy trabajando con una aplicación que tiene diferentes idiomas, por lo tanto, el JSON en cuestión que voy a mencionar puede cambiar acorde al idioma, además que es cargado de la base de datos y podría cambiar en el futuro, quiero utilizar el JSON como switch case, si es posible.

este es un ejemplo de uno de los JSON que puede recibir esta sección

```
businessTypes = {"1":"Restaurant","2":"Hotel","3":"Beauty shop","4":"Physiotherapist","5":"Dentist","6":"Bar","7":"Coffee shop"}
```

también tengo un inverso, ya que en realidad necesito trabajarlos al revés.

```
inverted = {"Restaurant":1,"Hotel":2,"Beauty shop":3,"Physiotherapist":4,"Dentist":5,"Bar":6,"Coffee shop":7}
```

POR EJEMPLO

```
for (let csvItem of csvResult){
   switch (csvItem["Business Type"]){
      case 'Restaurant': csvItem["Business Type"] = 1;
      break;
   }
}
```

Estos son datos que recibe la aplicación a través de un Excel que el cliente vaya a cargarle, ya que es multi idioma, los items del JSON podrían ser "Restaurant" o "Restaurante" o "飲食店"

por eso el switch, esos números son los ID de mi tabla en la base de datos, básicamente quiero hacer un switch case dinámico

por ejemplo el archivo va a contener celdas que sean "Restaurant" o "Coffee Shop", etc.

Si el archivo contiene "Restaurant" (o su equivalente en otros idiomas), necesito que se convierta en 1 (como está en el JSON)

```
case 'RESTAURANT': 1;
```

no al revés

es posible? :)

**actualización**

Lo que obtengo es que cuando la aplicación está en inglés, cargará en un input hidden todos los tipos de negocios que le mando desde laravel, como input hidden tengo lo siguiente

```
{"1":"Restaurant","2":"Hotel","3":"Beauty shop","4":"Physiotherapist","5":"Dentist","6":"Bar","7":"Coffee shop"}
```

un cliente subirá un archivo CSV, cuyas celdas pueden tener esas palabras, esas palabras serán cargadas en una DATATABLE (de hecho ya lo hace)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una vez importados los datos, tengo otro input hidden donde coloco en un array todos estos datos en la datatable, ya sea via importados o ingresados manualmente en un formulario, el input hidden es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podemos observar, tenemos la palabra "HOTEL" entre los importados, quiero transformar eso en un ID, ya que actualmente ese input lo que espera que un ID

**en palabras simples**

actualmente ese input está así

```
{"URL":"http://www.restaurant.com","Business Type":"Restaurant"}
```

pero en realidad **debería estar así**

```
{"URL":"http://www.restaurant.com","Business Type":"1"}
```

en otras palabras, ese input debería tener el ID (el número que está al lado) cada vez que encuentre la palabra "RESTAURANT" o las demás

Comment: No logré entender el problema concreto que planteas. Pero reflexionando sobre lo que he entendido, sería interesante saber una cosa: ¿siempre el JSON vendrá en un idioma específico o vendrá con idiomas mezclados? Si siempre estará en un idioma, sería mejor indicar en la cabecera del JSON en qué idioma viene, y para los términos usar una especie de diccionario. Creo que así te ahorrarías miles de líneas de código y tendrías todo centralizado.

Comment: en realidad, pensaba utilizar ese JSON como un CASE, por ejemplo, el primer item de ese JSON es Restaurant y tiene un 1 al lado, eso significaría case 'RESTAURANT': 1;

en otras palabras quiero que el JSON sea el case

Comment: No termino de entender el problema. Creas un objecto a partir de un JSON. A veces el *key* será numérico y otras veces será un *string*. Según yo lo veo, no hay mas que comprobar y transformar, ¿ no ?

Comment: ¿No sería más sencillo que guardes el tipo como número y tener un arreglo con los tipos disponibles de acuerdo al idioma cargado?

Comment: No no, esos JSON son diferentes, uno invertido y el otro no, podría usar cualquiera, el JSON contiene todos los posibles casos que vaya a recibir, podría usar uno o el otro, siempre y cuando pueda cumplir lo del CASE para que se convierta en el ID que tiene al lado

Comment: Pues ahora que te explicas entiendo menos :) La *sencillez* es fundamental en los asuntos complicados. Explícalo con sencillez, olvidándote del switch y demás historias. ¿Qué tienes y qué quieres lograr?

Comment: he actualizado la pregunta, desde donde dice actualización, espero que se entienda mejor

Comment: A ver, de tu actualización, para fines de una respuesta **óptima** a tu problema lo único que saco en claro es que cada negocio tiene su ID, supongo que en cualquier idioma (digamos 1=Restaurante, 2=Hotel, etc), ¿entendí bien hasta ahí? Del lío de los idiomas no explicas nada en la actualización, pero no hay problema. Esto sería bastante simple con una especie de tabla o diccionario estilo i18n donde guardarás asociado cada término a un ID y luego, según el idioma, mostrarías el término o la URL que se requiera o lo que sea.

Comment: Sí, cada tipo de negocio tiene su ID, este ID no cambia sea cual sea el idioma, lo que cambia es la palabra, la URL está bien como está, mi lío es la palabra, por ejemplo restaurant, que debería cambiar a 1

Comment: No entiendo mucho que lío tienes con la palabra. En la pregunta hablas de un JSON inverso, no sé para qué cuando hay formas de buscar por valor, extrayendo la clave asociada a ese valor y si estás en un contexto de servidor y tienes una base de datos ni te cuento, todo mucho más simple. No creo que sea necesario para este caso tener estructuras duplicadas. Por el valor Restaurante tú puedes saber cuál es su ID.

Comment: acabo de conseguirlo, utilizando el for, gracias por tus comentarios y ayudarme amigo, si no fuera por tus palabras mi pensamiento no iba a salir de ese switch case

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

Cambié el

```
  for (let csvItem of csvResult){
    switch (csvItem["Business Type"]){
       case 'Restaurant': csvItem["Business Type"] = 1;
             break;
       case 'Hotel': csvItem["Business Type"] = 2;
             break;
       case 'Beauty shop': csvItem["Business Type"] = 3;
             break;
       case 'Physiotherapist': csvItem["Business Type"] = 4;
             break;
       case 'Dentist': csvItem["Business Type"] = 5;
             break;
       case 'Bar': csvItem["Business Type"] = 6;
             break;
       case 'Coffee shop': csvItem["Business Type"] = 7;
             break;
       case 'レストラン': csvItem["Business Type"] = 1;
             break;
       case 'ホテル': csvItem["Business Type"] = 2;
             break;
       case '美容院 ': csvItem["Business Type"] = 3;
             break;
       case '接骨院': csvItem["Business Type"] = 4;
             break;
       case '歯医者': csvItem["Business Type"] = 5;
             break;
       case 'バー': csvItem["Business Type"] = 6;
             break;
       case 'カフェ': csvItem["Business Type"] = 7;
             break;
        }
 }
```

sí, es horriblemente largo, y se iba a poner peor.

por simplemente

```
for (let csvItem of csvResult){
     csvItem["Business Type"] = inverted[csvItem["Business Type"]];
  }
```

y se transformó el input a todo lo que necesitaba, cambiando las palabras por sus respectivos ID